# HTML/Javascript - Get text from online file

Tags: javascript, html

I have info that Shoutcast outputs as an html file.

The html file looks like this: `http://216.118.106.247:443/7.html`.

Is there any way to get the last item in that list/array into Javascript as a string?

I want to output the song info in a html file, I assume that once I get it into JS as a string that I can use the `document.write()` function to output the code...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you got PHP installed? You can use PHP, much easier.

Comment: Short of scraping the file on the server-side, I don't believe you can manipulate the contents of anything outside your own domain via javascript (unless of course there is a web-service which provides the data you need which you can call in your code).

Comment: Using this as part of a Google Chrome Extension, so I can't use PHP...

Answer (score 5):

If you look at http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html, you'll need to set up cross-origin requests and then you should be able to use the XMLHttpRequest to fetch the data.

EDITED:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = process;
xhr.open("GET", "http://216.118.106.247:443/7.html", true);
xhr.send();

function process()
{
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    // resp now has the text and you can process it.
alert(resp);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the resonse.
Can you help me with where to put the above code - in a <script type="text/javascript" > area, or in the page <head>?

Comment: I'm assuming you can put that in a `<script> section. I've looked at Chrome extensions, but never written one.

Comment: It'll be difficult to determine what specifically you're doing wrong without a code sample.

Comment: I was trying to put the code in my popup html page code and simply do a document.write() to the returned text to the page, but it wasn't working.
Think I'm going to give up for now...

Comment: Thanks for the help though, I'll get back to this a different time ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just write a javascript file (js file) and include with the script tags.

This file will have your data like that.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.js"  >
```

where data.js can be..

```
var data[];
data[0]="something";
```

e.t.c

In your page (the one that calls data.js) the array data will be accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest) aka Ajax requests.

There are a ton of libraries that make "Ajax" easy. Try this one:

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/request

There are limitations with what you can retrieve using ajax. Due to security issues your browser will not let javascript running on yourwebsite.com perform ajax requests to mywebsite.com.

Look up cross site scripting.

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods out there for you to use. But make sure files are in the **same** server or folder.

Using XMLHttpRequest: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/xmlhttpr.htm

Using FileSystemObject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czxefwt8(v=VS.85).aspx

Using a "helper" Java applet that reads a file or URL for your script

```
var fileContent='';
var theLocation='';

function readFileViaApplet(n) {
 document.f1.t1.value='Reading in progress...';
 document.ReadURL.readFile(theLocation);
 setTimeout("showFileContent()",100);
}

function showFileContent() {
 if (document.ReadURL.finished==0) {
  setTimeout("showFileContent()",100);
  return;
 }
 fileContent=document.ReadURL.fileContent;
 document.form1.textarea1.value=fileContent;
}
```

Some other source to reference: http://www.c-point.com/JavaScript/articles/file_access_with_JavaScript.htm (many examples).

Comment: Will this work if the file is on another server?
And how can I add this into my html file?

Comment: Javascript can't interact on server-side :) So you have to use PHP instead. It only works with files in the same server or folder.

Comment: Trying to get this working for a Google Chrome Extension, so I'm not sure if that's at all possible...

Comment: In this situation you're right, it's not possible ;) Maybe you should consider some other ways around.